# Actionscript Getter/setter class & scope in OOP

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, scope, getter-setter

Background:
I recently completed a tic-tac-toe game in AS3, using some simple function-based code I had written in C many years ago.
Now I'm on a quest to do it the "right way" using OOP techniques and best practices.
Everything is now divided into neat little packages, it looks pretty, and the last part of my journey is to get all the little buggers to communicate with each other.

My dilemma:
I want to move the code which holds the game state from my main to it's own class in com.okaygraphics.model.GameState.
The problem is nearly every other package gets and sets these game state properties.
I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to encapsulate this stuff, while still allowing my other classes to access it.

Where I'm at:

```
package com.okaygraphics.model{

    public class GameState {

        private var _player1State:uint=0x00000000;
        private var _player2State:uint=0x00000000;
        private var _activePlayer:int=0;


        public function get p1GameState():uint {
            return _player1State;
        }
        public function set p1GameState(value:uint):void {
            _player1State = value;
        }

        public function get p2GameState():uint {
            return _player2State;
        }
        public function set p2gameState(value:uint):void {
            _player2State = value;
        }

        public function get activePlayer():int {
            return _activePlayer
        }
        public function set activePlayer(value:int):void {
            _activePlayer = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Qestions:

1) Do I need a constructor? I mean, my program will never have more than one GameState. If I should call my getters/setters as instance methods, how do I get each other class to reference the SAME instance from their respective packages?

2) Do I even need getters and setters? Perhaps the class could just have 3 public properties? If so, how would I acheive the proper scope with regard to my other classes?

3) Should I assign everything to the class itself using the static keyword? If so, how would I implement and use those static methods?

4) Is this a mistake? Did I totally just program myself into a corner?

This seems like a pretty common task, yet one that I still don't fully understand. A brief explaination, some links, or the name of the technique I need would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
-Max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could approach this several different ways.

You could make `GameState` a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). That'll ensure that any instance of `GameState` is the same instance. Here's how to do that:

```
private static var _gameState:GameState;
private static var _allowInstantiation:Boolean;

public function GameState()
{
    if (!_allowInstantiation)
    {
        throw new Error("GameState is a Singleton. Use GameState.getInstance() instead of new GameState().");
    }
    else
    {
        _allowInstantiation = false;
    }
}

public static function getInstance():GameState
{
    if (!_gameState)
    {
        _allowInstantiation = true;
        _gameState = new GameState();
    }

    return _gameState;
}
```

Then, anytime you want to get `GameState`, you use this syntax:

```
var _gameState:GameState = GameState.getInstance();
```

By using a Singleton, you can still use the getters and setters you've already made, but the Singleton will ensure that every class that accesses `GameState` will be accessing the same instance.

Or, if you don't want to use a Singleton, you could make those private vars public static vars instead:

```
public static var player1State:uint=0x00000000;
public static var player2State:uint=0x00000000;
public static var activePlayer:int=0;
```

You'll no longer need the getters/setters, and you'd set them from other classes like this:

```
GameState.player1State = 0xFF0000;
GameState.player2State = 0xFF0000;
GameState.activePlayer = 1;
```

Either way you set up the Model, remember to put thought into how it'll be communicated with by the Controller and View. Remember that separation of Model and View is one of the main goals of the MVC pattern.

Comment: that singleton example is beautiful. just what i was looking for; thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1) What you could do is create **singleton** class. This is a class that is only intimated once. A quick google around (are search stackoverflow for AS3 Singleton) and you should find some good examples of a singleton class. With a singleton you only need to include the GameState class and you will be accessing the only one.

2) Can only do more good than harm having the getters and setters in there later on.

3) Can't really answer.

4) Nope. Seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to look at the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern and to use it in your game. (The game state is part of the **Model**.)

Now, as to how to access the game state from all other classes (this is the correct word not packages) you can use the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).